# C# Mock a custom interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I have this function that I am testing, which is called CreateMessageHistory, it has 2 dependencies, the IhttpClientFactory and another interface, I was able to mock the httpclient but I cant mock the interface

```
public class MessageHistoryService : IMessageHistoryService
{
    private const string API_MESSAGING_DB = "messages";
    private const string API_GET_MESSAGE_HISTORY_DESIGN = "_design/upn-timesent";
    private const string API_GET_MESSAGE_HISTORY_DESIGN_VIEW = "_view/upn-timesent-query";
    private readonly ICouchDbClients couchDbClient;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory clientFactory;


    public MessageHistoryService(
        IHttpClientFactory clientFactory,
        ICouchDbClients couchDbClient)
    {
        this.couchDbClient = couchDbClient ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(couchDbClient));

        this.clientFactory = clientFactory ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientFactory));
    }

    public async Task CreateMessageHistory(Message message)
    {
        var client = this.clientFactory.CreateClient(NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB);

        var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        formatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };

        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

        var response = await this.couchDbClient.AuthenticatedQuery(async () => {
            return await client.PutAsync($"{API_MESSAGING_DB}/{id.ToString()}", message, formatter);
        }, NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB, client);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

I seem to be having a problem about this interface...

```
public interface ICouchDbClients
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> AuthenticatedQuery(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> query, string name, HttpClient client);
}
```

Here is the implementation of that interface:

```
public class CouchDbClients : ICouchDbClients
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> authSessions;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Credentials> couchDbCredentials;
    private readonly IOptions<Clients> clients;
    private readonly string AuthCouchDbCookieKeyName = "AuthSession";

    public CouchDbClients(IOptions<Clients> clients)
    {
        this.clients = clients ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(couchDbCredentials));

        this.couchDbCredentials = new Dictionary<string, Credentials>();
        this.couchDbCredentials.Add(NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB, this.clients.Value.Work);

        this.authSessions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AuthenticatedQuery(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> query, string name, HttpClient client)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        do
        {
            Authenticate(name, client);
            response = await query();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                this.authSessions[name] = GenerateCookie(client, name);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpRequestException(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }

            counter++;
        } while (counter < 3);

        return response;
    }

    private void Authenticate(string name, HttpClient client)
    {
        CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
        var session = this.authSessions.ContainsKey(name);

        if (!session)
        {
            var newCookie = GenerateCookie(client, name);
            authSessions.Add(name, newCookie);
        }

        container.Add(
            client.BaseAddress,
            new Cookie(AuthCouchDbCookieKeyName, this.authSessions[name])
            );
    }

    private string GenerateCookie(HttpClient client, string name)
    {
        string authPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.couchDbCredentials[name]);

        var authResult = client.PostAsync(
            "_session",
            new StringContent(authPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            ).Result;

        if (authResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseHeaders = authResult.Headers.ToList();
            string plainResponseLoad = authResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            var authCookie = responseHeaders
                .Where(r => r.Key == "Set-Cookie")
                .Select(r => r.Value.ElementAt(0)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                int cookieValueStart = authCookie.IndexOf("=") + 1;
                int cookieValueEnd = authCookie.IndexOf(";");
                int cookieLength = cookieValueEnd - cookieValueStart;
                string authCookieValue = authCookie.Substring(cookieValueStart, cookieLength);
                return authCookieValue;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("There is auth cookie header in the response from the CouchDB API");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException(string.Concat("Authentication failure: ", authResult.ReasonPhrase));
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my unit testing :

```
[Fact]
    public async Task Should_NotThrowHttpRequestException_When_AMessageHistoryIsCreated()
        {
            var recipients = MockMessage.GetRecipients(279, 1, 2, 3);
            var message = MockMessage.GetMessage(recipients);

            mockStateFixture
                .MockMessageHistoryService
                .Setup(service => service.CreateMessageHistory(message));

            // ARRANGE
            var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);

            handlerMock
               .Protected()
               .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
                  "SendAsync",
                  ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
                  ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
               .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
               {
                   StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created
               })
               .Verifiable();

            // create the mock client
            // use real http client with mocked handler here
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(handlerMock.Object)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.179.236.207:5984/"),
            };

            mockStateFixture.MockIHttpClientFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateClient(NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB))
                                 .Returns(httpClient);

            //var httpResponseMessage = new Mock<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();


            //httpResponseMessage.Setup


            var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created
            };


            //httpResponseMessage.Setup(x => x.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created);

            //mockStateFixture.MockCouchDbClient.Setup(x => x.AuthenticatedQuery(
            //    async () =>
            //    {
            //        return await httpResponseMessage;
            //    },
            //    NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB,
            //    httpClient))
            //    .Returns(It.IsAny<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>);

            var messageHistoryService = new MessageHistoryService(
                mockStateFixture.MockIHttpClientFactory.Object, mockStateFixture.MockCouchDbClient.Object);

            var task = messageHistoryService.CreateMessageHistory(message);
            var type = task.GetType();
            Assert.True(type.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name == "VoidTaskResult");
            Assert.True(type.BaseType == typeof(Task));
            await task;
        }
```

How do I mock the ICouchDbClients, do I even have to?

This is the error I am getting:

Test Name:

> Data.Tests.MessageHistoryServiceTests+CreateMessageHistory.Should_NotThrowHttpRequestException_When_AMessageHistoryIsCreated
>   Test
>   FullName: Data.Tests.MessageHistoryServiceTests+CreateMessageHistory.Should_NotThrowHttpRequestException_When_AMessageHistoryIsCreated
>   Test Source:  C:\Data.Tests\MessageHistoryServiceTests.cs : line 36
>   Test Outcome: Failed Test Duration:   0:00:00.393

Result StackTrace:

> at Data.API.MessageHistoryService.CreateMessageHistory(Message
>   message) in C:\Data\API\MessageHistoryService.cs:line 51    at
>   Data.Tests.MessageHistoryServiceTests.CreateMessageHistory.Should_NotThrowHttpRequestException_When_AMessageHistoryIsCreated()
>   in C:\Data.Tests\MessageHistoryServiceTests.cs:line 100
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- Result Message:  System.NullReferenceException : Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Please add the error you are getting and explain what you are trying to do in more detail with your expected outcome.

Comment: @KieranDevlin Im not sure why I am getting that error. I cant seem to find its source, is it because I havent mocked the ICouchDbClient?

Comment: Have you added a break point into your code and stepped through to find what is actually null?

Comment: The point of mocking is to remove variables, so you can focus in on the part of the system you're actually trying to test. As such, your mocks should be as high-level as possible. For example, you don't need to mock an `HttpMessageHandler`. Just create a mock of `HttpClient` and stub out `SendAsync` to return a canned `HttpResponseMessage`. In the case of your `ICouchDbClients`, create a mock of that and stub `AuthenticatedQuery` entirely to again, return a canned `HttpResponseMessage` (which seems to be the return type of that). It doesn't matter what that method actually does.

Comment: @KieranDevlin I debugged and it seems that I am getting a null value from the var response part of the CreateMessageHistory function

Comment: @ChrisPratt you are right, it seems that I have to mock the ICouchDbClients, how do I do that using moq?

Comment: Just create `new Mock<ICouchDbClient>()`, then setup the `AuthenticatedQuery` to return a `HttpResponseMessage`

Comment: @netchkin yes I tried that by doing something like this  

`var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created
                };'


'mockStateFixture.MockCouchDbClient.Setup(x => x.AuthenticatedQuery(
                    It.IsAny<Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>>(),
                    NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB,
                    httpClient))
                    .Returns(httpResponseMessage);`

Comment: @netchkin but I am getting an Error: `CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>'`

Comment: @netchkin how do I return a Task<HttpResponseMessage>

Comment: use either `Task.FromResult` or Moq's `ReturnsAsync`